# How should one make up salah they missed while on a plane journey?

Tags: salat, travelling

I have heard that one should pray salah on the plane. However, sometimes people forget to pray salah. If they were on a plane journey, and they missed some salah, and when they land and remember salah, how should they make it up?

If I was to say a person had prayed Fajr and then went to the airport. This person then goes on the plane and its starts traveling to its destination and the journey takes 7 hours. During this time, he would have to pray salah. If the person was from the UK and their flight began at 10:00 am, it would take 7 hours for them to travel to their destination so the time is 17:00 pm in U.K. During this time, they forget to pray salah and miss zuhr and asr. In the U.K., it would be around the time to pray Maghrib. However, their destination is a different country where the time is different and the length of the day is different. This means that salah will be at different times in the day and they would be closer together in this destination.

Say the time at 17:00 pm GMT is 21:00pm in another country. At this time, in U.K., it would be Maghrib time. However, in their destination it would be Isha time.

Should they make up their prayers according to the prayers they would have missed in UK or make up the prayers they would have missed in their destination? So if you miss Zuhr and Asr according to UK time, but you miss Zuhr, Asr and Maghrib according to destination time, which of these Salah do you make up?

Comment: I guess this should cover your inquiry  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/how-to-pray-qaza-of-qasr-prayer/ and this is also relevant to some extent https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/are-we-obliged-to-reduce-prayer-when-on-a-journey

Comment: @Medi1Saif   Not really.